# Why does Qt crash when loading a window icon?

Tags: c++, qt, ubuntu

The following application crashes on `mainWindow->show();`

```
#include <QApplication>
#include <QFrame>
#include <QPixmap>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);
    Q_INIT_RESOURCE(resources);

    QPixmap pix;
    pix.load(":/resources/images/app/icon_glow.png");

    QFrame *mainWindow = new QFrame;
    mainWindow->setWindowIcon(QIcon(pix));
    mainWindow->show();

    return a.exec();
}
```

With the `mainWindow->setWindowIcon(QIcon(pix));` commented out, everything works. Otherwise, the backtrace (SEGFAULT, trying to dereference 0x8; seems like a missing nullptr check somewhere) is:

```
0   ??  /usr/local/Qt32/5.3/gcc/plugins/platforms/libqxcb.so        0xf4991138  
1   ??  /usr/local/Qt32/5.3/gcc/plugins/platforms/libqxcb.so        0xf4982d4c  
2   ??  /usr/local/Qt32/5.3/gcc/plugins/platforms/libqxcb.so        0xf498e7e3  
3   ??  /usr/local/Qt32/5.3/gcc/plugins/platforms/libqxcb.so        0xf498f0f4  
4   QWindowPrivate::applyCursor()   /usr/local/Qt32/5.3/gcc/lib/libQt5Gui.so.5      0xf7517942  
5   QWindowPrivate::setCursor(QCursor const*)   /usr/local/Qt32/5.3/gcc/lib/libQt5Gui.so.5      0xf75179f7  
6   QWindow::setCursor(QCursor const&)  /usr/local/Qt32/5.3/gcc/lib/libQt5Gui.so.5      0xf7517b16  
7   ??  /usr/local/Qt32/5.3/gcc/lib/libQt5Widgets.so.5      0xf7ad5d65  
8   QWidgetPrivate::show_sys()  /usr/local/Qt32/5.3/gcc/lib/libQt5Widgets.so.5      0xf7ad60b6  
9   QWidgetPrivate::show_helper()   /usr/local/Qt32/5.3/gcc/lib/libQt5Widgets.so.5      0xf7abab35  
10  QWidget::setVisible(bool)   /usr/local/Qt32/5.3/gcc/lib/libQt5Widgets.so.5      0xf7abb005  
11  QWidget::show() /usr/local/Qt32/5.3/gcc/lib/libQt5Widgets.so.5      0xf7aad77e  
12  main    main.cpp    17  0x804a21f
```

I tried loading the resource as follows:

```
QLabel *mainLabel = new QLabel;
mainLabel->setPixmap(pix);
mainLabel->show();
```

That works without a problem. Any help is greatly appreciated. Ubuntu 14.04 x64, compiled 32 bit, Qt 5.3

UPDATE: I reinstalled ubuntu-desktop (i reverted the desktop from 32 bit to 64 bit) and now I get an error:

```
The X11 connection broke: Maximum allowed requested length exceeded (code 4)
XIO:  fatal IO error 2 (No such file or directory) on X server ":0"
      after 409 requests (409 known processed) with 0 events remaining.
```

Comment: why not just `mainWindow->setWindowIcon(QIcon(":/resources/images/app/icon_glow.png"))` ?

Comment: @dschulz it was just a simplification (to show the problem wasnt with the loading of the resource). i tried it both ways, the same thing happens.

Comment: Are you using Qt creator? BTW, didn't you include the `<QIcon>` header?

Comment: @Tay2510 yes I am using QtCreator and i forgot to include it, but no warnings were given and compiling with it didnt make any difference

Comment: Sounds like a bug in Qt to me.

Comment: Did you compile Qt or got it "from the box" ? If second, then try to compile it

Comment: @borisbn from the box, compiling 32 bit Qt on 64 bit ubuntu sounds like a real pain :(

Comment: Downloaded Qt 5.3.0 and installed on a clean Ubuntu 14.04 (x86_64) machine. The code posted worked as expected. No warnings, no crashes. Couldn't reproduce the problem.

Comment: here's the complete code for reference: http://pastebin.com/q647rm5B

Comment: @dschulz did you install Qt 5.3.0 x86 (i.e. 32 bit version) on an x64 system like I did?

Comment: No, I installed the x64 version.. But to me remains unclear why would you do that. If you need to compile a x86 binary you could install VirtualBox (or similar) and have a clean x86 environment in a VM and then compile your project(s) and get x86 binaries from there.

Comment: @dschulz I use valgrind on this system heavily and I would rather not take any unnecessary performance hits. Furthermore, the executable should be able to run on both x86 and x64 environments, so this is a good test of that.

Answer (score 4):

I have also encountered this. The reason is the icon is too large. Resize to something smaller, 256x256 for example.